# Removing Community Wiki status

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

I was unaware that making too many edits to your own answer will cause it to go into community wiki mode. I wrote a rather long answer that took a lot of time and research, and over the course of its lifetime I've edited it several times to correct myself and to build a complete answer. I was wondering if it is possible to have the CW mode status removed, at least just this once? Not a big deal for me, but thought it'd be worth it to ask.

Comment: How many edits are "too much"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Even as a site mod, there is no way to do this. It's happened to one of my best answers too, and it isn't reversible. I'm sorry.</strike>

If you plan on putting a lot of work into an answer, I suggest doing your editing in a different editor. If you're really working on a good answer, it showing up an hour or day or even week later than other answers because you invested the research and editing time isn't going to be a real problem.

And sometimes, it's just going to happen. I had one highly upvoted answer I put a lot of time into that several different people edited punctuation back and forth and kicked it over to CW so I'm not getting anything from it any more.

Done.

Just a quick warning to keep in mind for the future: editing an answer bumps to whole thread to the home page. If you are making substantial content edits and improving a valuable piece of content, that's fine. If you are just tweaking things because you feel like it and the regular site visitors have already seen your content bumped a time or two, it might be time to let it go until there is a significant reason for a revision.

In particular I would say that editing to fix formatting/style issues is fine on an answer that is already on the home page. Also editing to change a statement or add references or whatever is fine, but a simple word bolding or capitalization isn't a good reason to bump.

Comment: [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373) says mods can remove them at their discretion?

Comment: @Shredder: Wadd'ya know. I don't know where I got my bad information but you seem to be correct.

Comment: Thanks Caleb :) Yes, I can see how that would be annoying. Thanks for the advice too~ Last time I will ask for this.

Comment: @Shredder: No problem, that warning is general reference for others that come along. I don't want people editing at will knowing we can roll back CW, that system is there for a reason. But I see how you got yourself into that position. Now to go fix that one of my own!